# Split date in javascript

Tags: jquery, javascript

How to split the following date in javascript,

```
 var date='2002-01-01';
   The result should be as 20020101
```

Thanks..

Comment: jQuery: The future of Javascript. 8-)

Comment: @Matt: lol.  This sort of stuff always reminds me of bobince's jQuery rant - http://www.doxdesk.com/updates/2009.html#u20091116-jquery

Comment: @Matt jQuery: the history of javascript. 8-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var date = "2002-01-01";
```

Either of the following will get you what you want:

- `date = date.replace(/-/g, "");`
- `date = date.split("-").join("");`

Answer (score 4):

If it is just a string, you can do:

```
var date = ("2002-01-02").replace(/-/g, "");
```

Otherwise:

```
var now = new Date();
var date = now.getFullYear() + "" + (now.getMonth() + 1) + "" + now.getDate();
```